# selenium remote driver: cannot accept alert on window close- Window not found exception

Tags: selenium

I have a window popup , as soon as i click on the submit button the popup window closes and a javascript alert appears.

I have been getting : window not found exception in the logs. 
If the window would not closed ,selenium is able to identify the alert but since the popup has closed I get the above exception.

I have tried using $driver->switch_to_window after clicking the submit button but that doesn't  handle the alert.

Any thoughts is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the alert functionality with Selenium?

```
public void checkAlert() {
    try {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        alert.accept();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //exception handling
    }
}
```